# Alerts Per User On Custom List Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, classic-experience

I have a client who has a calendar set up and they want to use alerts, but the issue is at the moment everyone with alerts gets an alert. They use the calendar for time off requests so only a user's manager would approve it. Ideally the managers just want to get an alert IF the request is theirs to approve.

Would creating a view with a [Me] filter and having the managers set an alert on that view work?

Obviously this would be easily doable with a task list, but the head of the team does not want to start over.

For what it is worth they are using classic view and not modern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what column you would set the [Me] filter for your view on.

One possibility is you could add a required column called 'Manager' to make employees pick their manager when they enter an item, and create a view for each manager on that list.  Then setup an alert for each manager, triggering when someone changes an item that appears in that manager's view. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So creating a manager column and then creating a view with the filter [Me] and then having managers set an alert on that view specifically actually causes only that manager to get an alert. I can't explain why it works but it does. Your way 100% would have worked though.